# Specify android.useAndroidX per subproject with AGP 4.2.0

Tags: android, gradle

I have a rather large gradle tree with multiple android projects. Some of them use androidX, but most - do not (they are compiled to separate, mostly but not completely independent apks). With Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) <= 4.1.3 I specified `android.useAndroidX=true` in `gradle.properties` of subprojects, that use androidX, not in root `gradle.properties`.

But AGP 4.2.0 doesn't read `gradle.properties` from subprojects dirs any more and uses root  `gradle.properties` solely: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.2-gradle-properties . So, I need some way to specify `android.useAndroidX=true` not globally, but for chosen subprojects. Is there such a way ?

Comment: Why would you like to do that for AndroidX? I understand that the reason may be that some of your libraries are migrated to AndroidX and some not. Am I correct? If so, the libraries that are not migrated probably will end up being "translated" to AndroidX by the Jetifier, meaning the compilation will be slower.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Jetifier is really an option, and I consider it. But I haven't try it yet for that project, and besides slower compilation it will require an excessive amount of testing to avoid possible degradation and regressions. That's why I would just prefer an option to choose where to use AndroidX and where not.

Comment: My point is that the reason of existence of Jetifier is to allow modules with AndroidX and Support library to coexist in a single app, so I don't know if it's really an option or a must. A Support-based library needs to go through Jetifier to be able to work in an AndroidX app, I'm not that sure about the oposite. So, depending on the structure of your app properties maybe you were (implicitly) in the previous scenario before. You should share how `android.useAndroidX=true` (and `false` or inexistence) is used in your `gradle.properties` in the project hierarchy to really know.